# Commercial software using open source library: legal notice

Tags: law, attribution, apache-2.0, license-file

Is there any legal constraint saying that a commercial software must quote the open source libraries and public domain libraries regardless of the open source license type?

For example, let's say I develop a web application based on java servlet and I include (and use without modifications) a library licensed under Apache License 2.0.

Then I will sell my .war file that includes it.

Do I have to include a text file saying I am using it? What would/could happen if I don't?

Comment: If this is not the right place to ask, can you please point me to the right stack Exchange website?

Comment: Why hello there! Your question is perfectly on-topic for the site. Have fun :)

Comment: As a matter of courtesy, it is a good thing to include a thank you notice mentioning free software projects you are using, as part of a README or similar. (Yes, I know the question asks about legal requirements.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends upon the license, and you can find out by reading the license.  Many, such as Apache-2.0 require the license to accompany binary distributions, but some certified as Open Source don't.  Some (for example zlib, libpng) ask politely for credit.  libjpeg requires attribution, but in order to get certified as Open Source they promised not to enforce it.

Comment: What are you talking about? [The majority of these licenses require the author's copyright statement to be maintained in binary distributions.](http://opensource.org/licenses)

Comment: Ok, let's focus on apache license 2.0 for example. If my software is not open source, do I have any obligation to my customer to explicit that I am using it?

Comment: I am not saying not to maintain it. E.g. the jar file that I use, includes already its apache license file. My question is: do I have also an obligation to say somewhere that I use it?

Comment: @curiousdannii yes of course the copyright must be retained inside the binary redistribution of the library.  The question seems to be about whether the copyright notice must also be displayed by the application.

Comment: As I said, read the license! Apache-2.0 does require you to provide a copy of the license with Apache-2.0-licensed binaries (i.e., distributions in "Object Form"). See section 4.1 of the license. –

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Section 4.4 would indicate that you would have to display it within the application or in its documentation or some equivalent, at least as long as the copyright notice is in a NOTICE file.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes.  There seem to be really two questions here. 1: must the library license be distributed along with a binary of an application that uses the library, and 2: must the application display to the end user the fact that it uses the library?.  And the answer to either is found by reading the license.

Comment: @Glenn Thank you for the clarification. I read the license, no need for exclamation marks. Simply I was not sure of the Object form definition.

Comment: However, part of the question is still unanswered. Is the legal obligation depending on the license only? If so, if a library is of public domain or it's not covering the Object form case, is there any constraint?

Comment: @ChaSIem I don't think the remaining part of the question can be answered here.  It's a legal question requiring your lawyer to interpret it.  It depends upon your jurisdiction, whether "Moral" rights exist along with Copyright rights, etc.  It has happened to me (redistribution of my software with attribution removed) and I didn't like it, but I don't have a battalion of lawyers enforce the license.

Comment: So I think that even if I release my library as public domain there is still a possibility to be quoted :) thank you very much for sharing your experience